# JMeter 3.1 adding extra quotes, CSV Data Set Config

Tags: jmeter

I have a problem with reading quoted data from a CSV file. I need the data from the file for the Post Body Data.

The Post Body contains among other variables the variable:

"words": ${words}

And in the CSV file the data for the variable looks like this:

"ABC", "CBA", "BAC", "XXX", ...

JMeter will add additional quotation marks while sending the request, like ""ABC"", ""CBA"" ...

I have tried to set "Allow quoted data?" true, but then it doesn't separate the complete string anymore. As delimiter I am using ";". All the string will be put in the first variable.

Can anyone help me with this that JMeter doesn't double the quotation marks? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing your CSV file and CSV Data Set Config setup so a couple of "generic" recommendations:

1. How about removing quotation marks from the CSV data and putting them to the HTTP Request sampler's body data like:

   ```
   "words": "${words}"
   ```

   and in the CSV you will have: `ABC,CBA,BAC,XXX`
2. If your CSV file contains one variable per one line you can go for [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function

   ```
   "words": ${__StringFromFile(/path/to/your/file.csv,,,)}
   ```
3. "Extra" quotation marks can be removed using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   "words" : ${__groovy(vars.get('words').replaceAll('\"\"'\, '\"'),)}
   ```

And last but not the least, as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to the [latest stable version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) as soon as possible